KVM breaks my host's Internet connection
When the host first boots, route says:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp3s0

And ping 8.8.8.8 says:
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=6.40 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=6.36 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=6.37 ms

After a minute (I think after my KVM guests are up?), route says:
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 macvtap1
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 macvtap0
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 macvtap2
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 macvtap1
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 macvtap0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 macvtap2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 macvtap0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 macvtap1
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 enp3s0
192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 enp3s0

And ping 8.8.8.8 says:
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 169.254.245.85 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.245.85 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 169.254.245.85 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

And ip a says:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp12s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:d5:47:aa:6c:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 38:d5:47:aa:6c:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:2d:7e:13:f7:d6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.97/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7a2d:7eff:fe13:f7d6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: macvtap0@enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 08:00:27:f5:3b:9b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.161.146/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global macvtap0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef5:3b9b/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: macvtap1@enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 08:00:27:eb:28:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.245.85/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global macvtap1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:feeb:283d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: macvtap2@enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,DYNAMIC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 08:00:27:d7:49:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 169.254.144.158/16 brd 169.254.255.255 scope global macvtap2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed7:49ee/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

cat /etc/network/interfaces says:
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp

I have nothing in /etc/network/interfaces.d/.  I'm on Debian 12.  Some LAN networking works, but the host has no Internet connection.  The guests can access the Internet.
What do I have misconfigured and how can I fix it?

you must set up a bridge as documentation says: https://wiki.debian.org/KVM#Setting_up_bridge_networking

There's probably a way to add a route metric to the virtual NICs.  Find it and set it to something high. I think the NetworkManager penalty for no Internet connection is 20k so you might want to set something like 24k.

Where do your addresses for the macvtap's come from? Probably some DHCP server? If so: remove the gateway from that DHCP-server.

I didn't set up anything for the inet 169.254.245.85/16 addresses.  I don't know where they come from.  I suppose KVM does something for me?  The guests get IP addresses from my LAN's router.

I don't know why route listed different routes when I posted than it does now, but I've since learned that everything's find until I boot one of the VMs.  When I boot that one, I get a route that I have to delete like sudo route del -net default gw 0.0.0.0 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev macvtap2 and then things are fine until I start that VM again.

No interface gets an IP address via magic. If you did not set it yourself, there is a DHCP server that hands-out the IP address. That DHCP server also gives the (non existing) additional default gateways. You need to find the config of that DHCP server and remove the distribution of the default gateway from it.
